# how to make invisible existing field Quotation Date from sales in odoo 13

Tags: python-3.x, xml, odoo, odoo-13

I am trying make invisible field **Quotation Date** which field is **date_order** in sales odoo13 community.

quotation_product.xml

```
<xpath expr="/form/sheet/group/group/field[@name='date_order']" position="attributes">
    <attribute name="invisible" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', 'in',['sale', 'done', 'cancel'])]}" >1</attribute>
</xpath>
```

using above code field is invisible but field name **Quotation Date** is showing in **quotataion** **state**, I am also trying to make invisible **Order Date** which field is **date_order** in **sales order** **state**,this will shows After clicking confirm button in sales.

Comment: Hello Mr op, You are trying to add the attribute invisible but in default, odoo has the same condition.

Comment: when you want to change the visibility dynamically use `attrs` not `invisible`.  `<attribute name="attrs"....`

Comment: @DipenShah plesae explain in details, i want to hide field Quotation Date from base (existing).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with following code, It will hide permanently Odoo base field.

```
<xpath expr="/form/sheet/group/group/field[@name='date_order']" position="attributes">
    <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute>
</xpath>
```

If you want to hide field base on condition, use following style.

```
<xpath expr="/form/sheet/group/group/field[@name='date_order']" position="attributes">
    <attribute name="attrs">{'invisible': [('state', 'in', ['sale', 'done', 'cancel'])]}</attribute>
    <!--attribute name="attrs">{'invisible': [('field_name', 'operator', condition)]}</attribute-->
</xpath>
```

NOTE: Use `invisible` attribute name for hide permanently and `attrs` for condition based visibility